# Getting keys from JSON using volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

```
{
"ResponseType": "success",
"ResponseMessage": "success",
"Personal Preference": [
{
  "Questionno": 3,
  "TokenKey": "150920150252340989472d8d09fc6563",
  "QuestionText": "Km per jaar",
  "QuestionType": "Slider",
  "QuestionOrder": 3,
  "answerOptionList": [],
  "Answer": "16014",
  "Unit": "KM",
  "Minimum": 1,
  "Maximum": 100000,
  "SliderOptionList": [
    "<1000",
    "1000-1500",
    "1501-2000",
    "2001-3000",
    "3001-5000",
    ">5000"
  ]
```

The above is the JSON which i receive from the server using Volley. I need to get only the Keys(ResponseType, ResponseMessage, Personal Preference: these might varry) from this JSON and store in an array.

Comment: Iterator<String> iter = json.keys(); will return you a iterator of keys

Comment: You need the keys or the values corresponding to the above mentioned keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
Iterator iterator   = jsonObject.keys();
List<String> keysList = new ArrayList<String>();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) iterator.next();
    keysList.add(key);
}
```